# Swift: UICollectionView - Fixed space between cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using `UICollectionView` for a list of `UIButton` of different sizes. In Storyboard, I set leading and trailing constraints for the collection view (20px each related to Safe Area). That's what I get:

[image: result]

As you can see, the space between cells (that I set in Storyboard) is increased in order to "justify" the cells. That's not what I want, I'd like to have fixed space between cells and eventually more space a the end of the row. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class CustomImageFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override init() {
    super.init()
    setupLayout()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupLayout()
}

func setupLayout() {
    minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    minimumLineSpacing = 1
    scrollDirection = .vertical
}

override var itemSize: CGSize {
    set {

    }
    get {
        let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 3 //no of columns

        let itemWidth = (self.collectionView!.frame.width - (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth + 5)
    }
}
}


On your collection view controller 

@IBOutlet weak var colectionvw: UICollectionView!

var collectionViewLayout: CustomImageFlowLayout!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionViewLayout = CustomImageFlowLayout()
    colectionvw.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout
}
```

Comment: I don't want to have fixed number of columns, it depends on the width of the buttons (and screen of course)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by making CollectionView scrollDirection set to Horizontal. This will automatically set the size and arrange it as you want.

Comment: It scrolls horizontally on a single row

Comment: No you can set height to your collectionview for multiple rows.

Comment: How can I set the height if I don't know it? I'm currently updating it using collectionView.contentSize.height

Comment: Add collectionview constraints according to your layout and fix its height.